Python to dupliacte pointed collection with new objects
As in topic. I have a code which is copying objects, but sadly then there is a delay, and the dependencies to for example Constraints are then pointing to the original object. So I came up to an idea, that instead of copying objects in collections, better would be to copy entire collection first, then all the dependencies are preserved. But I can't get it to work anyhow.
How to call in the script, to take given collection, and duplicate it with creating new objects, not to link?
